# Save value when temporarily opening new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm doing a task app where you can have date/location reminders. I would like to know if there are anyway to temporarily save the data in the fields in the picture when opening mapView to select address or do I have to pass those fields to the mapView to then re set them when coming back to the addTaskVC?

[image: values I want to keep]

Comment: There are ways to pass arguments through `ViewController` using `segue`(override `prepare()`), but I suggest to use `global variables` or `static` members of a "gateway" `class`.

Comment: Pls mention your flow , From where you are showing Mapview , is it in current navigation .  hierarchy ? ,

Comment: When you press the remind me on location there is a button to show the mapVC so yes it's in the current navigation hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a global stuct to save my temp variables to and then loaded them in inside viewDidLoad or where there where needed to load

**Global Struct**

```
struct tempVariablees {

    static var taskTextField = ""
    static var dateField = ""
    static var dateSelected = false

}
```

**ViewDidLoad**

```
if tempVariablees.taskTextField != "" {
        taskText.text = tempVariablees.taskTextField
    }
    if tempVariablees.dateField != "" && tempVariablees.dateSelected{
        dateSelected.text = tempVariablees.dateField
        remindMeOnDay.isOn = true
        userPickedDate = tempVariablees.dateSelected
    }
```